# Joomla internal only page

Tags: joomla, apache2

I have a LAMP setup and Joomla. I want to have some URLs/pages in my Joomla website only internally to my subnet. Is there a file/URL equivalent for `Directory` like this?

```
<Directory /usr/share/biowiki>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
    Allow from subnet-address
</Directory>
```

Or is there any alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

did it my self using Location

```
<Location /contact/login-here>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Order deny,allow
   deny from all
   Allow from subnet-ip
</Location>
```

this will mean URL http://mywebserver.com/contact/login-here is viewable only locally.